# Dropping Columns referenced by other Tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Hi I have 3 Tables Cases, Programs, Violations, now all these Tables are related as ManyToMany with Notice Table, but earlier they were having OneToMany, but now they are related ManyToMany, hence I moved them all to the Associated Table to handle it, which is called as ManyToMany table which has PK, ParentyEntity, ParentEntityId (which is PK of Notices table), ChildEntity, ChildEntityId - I have to do it with Entity Framework Code First Migrations - hence I am trying to be very cautious here.
What am I planning are
1.Take backup of the Database
2. Migrate Data from tables to ManyToMany table
3. Record all the Foreign Key Constraints first (like generate scripts for those FKs references) then drop all those Foreign Keys
4. Then Drop tables using Entity Framework Code First Migrations.

Can somebody please help me if I am missing anything and are there any easy fool proof ways to do the same and how to drop columns using Entity Framework Migrations - I have lost touch with Code First approach, I understand its tough and needed very careful implementation - any suggestion any help would be very very helpful. Actually the Database has already have been implementing this - but they didn't drop the old columns and didn't delete the data from old columns - hence its creating or showing inconsistent Data, the old programmer has left it in between - need a lot of suggestions and support - thanks a lot.

Comment: why dont you create a New database. Build the specs from ground up. You can use Stored Procs to populate from OLD_DB to NEW_DB using insert OR better MERGE statements. do validations like Count checks, metric checks. AND Still let the old db be populated by old ETL method while you work up the new one.

Comment: NEW_DB approach also lets you post test script with test data; and any questions you may have you can ask the community (provided you share what work you have done around it). Hope it helps. Because w/o sample code it be very tough for anyone to help you. This is a design question than tech implementation right now.

Comment: Yeah it is design question than a Tech hence I couldn't post sample code or something. But tough decision to make though

Comment: try the new_db design. That way you can choose a historic month, week, day and build and test your process. Then Stop old_db process and continue to put newer data into New_db. Personally, for me since I work more on reporting/OLAP style side; I do not like to enforce a lot of PK/FK constraints. PK's only in form of indexes for faster queering of data. Hence if I'm asked to design my solution will be for faster selects vs data integrity/consistency (WHICH YOU NEED) Hence build VALIDATIONS.